# Dax formula for power bi that gives the last value of a column based on the latest date and time on another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in the following format:

```
Name         date
abc          8/21/2018 2:00 PM
def          8/21/2018 2:00 PM
ghi          8/20/2018 1:00 PM
xyz          8/19/2018 3:00 PM
```

I am trying to create a bool column in Power BI which turns 1 if the values are the latest in the date column according to date as well as time.

I need to show basically filter the corresponding rows `abc` and `def` that have the latest date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this as a calculated column, you just need to use the `MAX` function inside an `IF`:

```
Bool = IF(Table1[date] = MAX(Table1[date]), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying the last function thinking it will pick out the last date.